# Error converting cell to date using datenum() in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, cell

I have a very large <1165900 x 1 cell> 'a' that I want to convert into datenum. I've done this somehow before but it has stopped working for me. Instead, I get the following error now:

```
Error using datenum (line 179)
DATENUM failed.

Caused by:
    Error using dtstr2dtnummx
    Failed on converting date string to date number.
```

I've just written this as the code:

```
b = datenum(a, 'dd.mm.yyyy HH.MM.SS.FFF');
```

Does anyone know what I've done wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax into `datenum` is correct, are you certain that `a` is formatted correctly?

Here is some code I used to verify the syntax into `datenum` was correct:

```
%define format string
fmt = 'dd.mm.yy HH.MM.SS';

%create dateString using current time
dStr = datestr(now, fmt);

%convert num to string with datenum
dNum = dateNum(dStr, fmt);
```